# safari navigation bar... How to reproduce it?

Tags: iphone, safari, navigation, drawing, uinavigationbar

I'm developing a new application that use a webView for internet searches...

I'd like to reproduce the navigation bar as Safari's bar but I don't know how do.
How can I create a navigation bar with label and two text fields programmatically?
Does anyone know a tutorial, link or guide to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: New version of this question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducing it exactly will take some studying and development.  You might start with the Apple sample code [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html), and with the knowledge gained tackle a more exact replica.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but thanks for showing me this source... I'll analyze it! :)