# hiding the navigation bar like instagram or Facebook in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar

I had an application in which I want to hide my navigation bar when scrolling upwards in a `UITableView`. I am doing like this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

    //Initializing the views and the new frame sizes.
    UINavigationBar *navbar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    UIView *tableView = self.view;

    CGRect navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    CGRect tableFrame = self.view.frame;

    //changing the origin.y based on the current scroll view.
    //Adding +20 for the Status Bar since the offset is tied into that.
    navBarFrame.origin.y = MIN(0, (sender.contentOffset.y * -1)) +20;
    navbar.frame = navBarFrame;

    tableFrame.origin.y = MIN(0,MAX(-44,(sender.contentOffset.y * -1)));
    tableView.frame = tableFrame;    
}
```

But the problem is that it is moving completely upwards in iOS 7. I need it to be stopped under the status bar and the status bar is shown there.

Comment: have a look at this library https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar

Comment: Have you tried any of these solutions?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar

Comment: i tried all of them,in the first one when scrolling starts content offset is changing not coming back to 0

Comment: The project mentioned by @Thedude is pretty easy to use. But when the navigation bar reappears, there is a gap added between the tableview and the navigation bar. How do I prevent/remove that gap?

Comment: @KatedralPillon A comment in one question is not the place to ask another question. Try asking a new question with details of your issue to get some help.

Comment: @Thedude I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839112/a-more-complete-library-to-contract-expand-navigation-bar

Comment: Did you try `    self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;` on your viewDidAppear method?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ninjinkun/NJKScrollFullScreen ...Hope this will help any other