# How to do hide navigation bar when scroll view (look like Facebook)?

Tags: iphone, facebook, uinavigationbar

I have to do hide navigation bar when down scroll and show when top scroll look like in Facebook. How to do?

Comment: Please do research before you ask questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods, for example: --->

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //animate your view here when you scroll
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    //reset your view to the initial position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect Scrolling using UIScrollView Delegates

and use

[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES]; // will hide NavigationBar