# UITableView: Shrink Tab Bar and Navigation Bar on Swipe up

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

**Scenario**

I have an app that uses a Tab Bar Controller (bottom of the screen) with a Navigation Controller (top of the screen) UI design. On one view controller I have a UITableView with content that the user will "Swipe Up" for to scroll through the table to view the content.

**Need**

Much like the Yahoo! and Instagram app, I'd like to be able to have the top Nav Bar and the bottom Tab Bar "shrink" and "disappear" when it senses the user is swiping up on the tableView. And of course, when the user swipes down again, I'd like them both to reappear.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar

Comment: Hello @Claudio thank you for your response. I did see that and I got it working in my app. Problem is, When my navigation controller pushes to another screen **while the navigation bar is still hidden** it stays hidden in the next screen. Do you know how to bring the navigation controller back?

Comment: Re-set the position of tabBar/navigationBar frame on viewDidAppear of each UIViewController you create. It should work fine. I just don't remember now what is the exact height of navigation anda tab bar in this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide `UITabbar` of `UITabbarController` which contains `UINavigationController` with `UITableViewController` in stack one should use `hidesBarsOnSwipe` property and add custom selector for `barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer`:

```
@implementation SomeTableViewController

- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    if (parent) {
        self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
        [self.navigationController.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)];
    }
    else {
        self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = NO;
        [self.navigationController.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer removeTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)];
    }
}

- (void)swipe:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UINavigationBar *bar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;

    BOOL isHidden = (bar.frame.origin.y < 0);

    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:isHidden];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:isHidden withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

In this way one can hide both tabbar and statusBar. Also one can add some animation effects for hiding/revealing these bars.

It is very important to remove selector before `self` has been deallocated. Otherwise, you will get guaranteed crash on the next use of `barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer` with `self.navigationController`.

Note this approach is admissible only for iOS8+.