# hidesBarsOnSwipe with UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I recently switched to using a `UITabBarController` within my app and was not amused to find I could not make `hidesBarsOnSwipe` work with it. I use to simply say (within the view controller) `hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`, but now that does not work. If someone could help me make this work, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with `hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;`? If it doesn't help provide some code for us to investigate.

Comment: @carlodurso - I'm in Swift.

Comment: Try `self.navigationController!.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`, hidesBarsOnSwipe is only included in NavigationController, it may later be added to UITabBarController, it did worked for me in a case that UITabBarController is the initial controller, and both items are embedded in NavigationController, by adding this code in both items's viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @Zout, you can find exact solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32445701/2066428)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I had embedded the `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController`, which I had put as the root view controller for the window. After I made the root just the tab bar controller, it worked like a charm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can add action to the hideOnSwipe like below

```
[self.navigationController.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(swipeGesture:)];
```

Add what ever code you want in the swipeGesture method. Hide/unhide tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

in swift3

```
  self.navigationController?.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "swipeGestuere")
```

declare a variable hidden which helps to get the tab bar back

```
 func swipeGestuere() {
    if (hidden == true){         
    self.bottomTabBar.isHidden = true
        hidden = false
    }
    else{
        self.bottomTabBar.isHidden = false
        hidden = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by [resizing](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUKit/blob/master/Source/Additions/UITabBarController+NBUAdditions.m#L34) the `UITabBarController` just enough to get the tab bar out of the screen:

```
- (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden
{
    CGRect frame = self.originalViewFrame;
    if (hidden)
    {
        frame.size.height += self.tabBar.size.height;
    }
    self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

---

Then you can add KVO your scroll view:

```
[scrollView addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
                context:nil];
```

And hide/show the tab bar on scroll:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    CGPoint oldOffset = [(NSValue *)change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] CGPointValue];

    if (!_hidesBarsOnScroll || _scrollView.contentOffset.y == oldOffset.y)
        return;

    // Show on scroll up
    if (_barsHidden &&
        scrollView.contentOffset.y < oldOffset.y &&
        scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height < scrollView.contentSize.height) // Skip on bottom
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO
                                                 animated:YES]; // Also navigation bar!
        [self.tabBarController setTabBarHidden:NO
                                      animated:YES];
        _barsHidden = NO;
    }

    // Hide on scroll down
    if (!_barsHidden &&
        scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && // Skip on top
        scrollView.contentOffset.y > oldOffset.y)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES
                                                 animated:YES];
        [self.tabBarController setTabBarHidden:YES
                                      animated:YES];
        _barsHidden = YES;
    }
}
```

You can take a look to this implementation [here](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUKit/blob/cb779c27dad2a7b2400639abbf518c5d5c178a6d/Library/NBUCompatibility/ScrollViewController.m#L765).

Comment: I need to have the tab bar hide when I swipe up in the scroll view in the UIViewController.

Comment: You just need to call `setTabBarHidden:` on scroll. Added sample code for that as well but you can do it differently if you want.