# Xcode: Getting rid of black bar when hiding navigation bar

Tags: ios, uitableview

**Scenario**

I have an app that allows users to scroll up on a UITableView to view posts. When they scroll up the navigation bar will hide. I use the code from the following SO post...

[Imitate iOS 7 Facebook hide/show expanding/contracting Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar)

**Problem**

When I tried the first answer on there it worked the first time I used it, perfectly. After I got it to where it was working I tried to get my Tab Bar to drop down as well. When I fidgeted around with my code I must have fudged something up. Because now when I run the same code, I get this black bar that won't go away.

**Unscrolled (normal)**

[image]

**Scrolled Up (leaves ugly black bar)**

[image]

**What I've also tried**

GTScrollNavigationBar
and TLYShyNavBar

and they both leave the black bar also...

**Question**

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Check the size of your view. It might not extend behind the nav bar so when you hide the nav bar there's nothing behind it so it's black.

Comment: Yes, extend your view height. Increase AppDelegate.window height and set origin.y for that to make sure it starts from top.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think your issue here has to do with your navigation bar not being transparent. In your view controller, make sure the property **Under Opaque Bars** is checked and it should be fine.

[image]

Another way to doing that is to set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `YES` (not the default) on your view controller.

Comment: I am using AVCapture session to scan the qr code after this . qr code detecter bounds using `objectCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject` is not at correct place. qrcode image is beneath box starting

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to just do it in code for full control and additional possibilities later on.

Simply set the background color of the concerned tableview. In your case that would be something like this:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```