# How to make Navigation bar height become smaller when UITableView scroll down?

Tags: ios

How to make `UINavigationBar` height become smaller when `UITableView` scroll down?

And when scroll up, the  `UINavigationBar` height back to normal,
just like what safari does.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ton of third party options to create an effect like that. I'd start by looking at this question on SO:
[Imitate Facebook hide/show expanding/contracting Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar)