# Hide navigation bar on scroll with animation Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, scrollview, navbar

Some apps (facebook, 9gag) have this functionality. When the user scrolls up the navigation bar gradually hides itself to a point where vanishes. Then when the user scrolls down the navigationBar gradually shows itself (depending on the speed of the scroll).

We tried to implement this on **Titanium** by adjusting the height of the nav view on the scroll event, but it is lagged and very slow:

```
scrollView.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){ 
        boolScroll=true;
});

scrollView.addEventListener('scroll',function(e){ 
    if(boolScroll){
        auxScroll=e.y;
        boolScroll=false;
    }
    var bh=bars.height;
    var sh=scrolls.height;

    if(auxScroll<e.y)//scrolling down
        if(bars.height>appHeight*0.08){
            bars.height=bh-appHeight*0.005; //rate for hiding
            if(scrolls.height<appHeight*0.7)
                scrolls.height=sh+appHeight*0.005;//same rate to increase the height of the scroll
        }

    if(auxScroll>e.y)//scrolling up
        if(bars.height<appHeight*0.08){
            bars.height=bh+appHeight*0.005; 
            if(scrolls.height>appHeight*0.7)
                scrolls.height=sh-appHeight*0.005;  
        }
});
```

We also tried doing it with translate animation on the view, but is still slow.

There is a solution for iOS on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar) question. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: There is an open issue in Titanium JIRA https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18912 but nobody touch it for year. :(

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you solved this problem but I did a trick that's working well for me ( at least for the navigation bar ) 
Here's the snippet :

```
self.addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
        if(e.contentOffset.y > 20) NavigationWindow.window.hideNavBar();
        if(e.contentOffset.y < 20) NavigationWindow.window.showNavBar();
    });
```

***NavigationWindow is an instance of Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow, self can be a tableview,view,scrollview or a window ( in my example )***

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a really nice feature to have. Appcelerator just tackled it and should be available on release 6.0 according to this ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23684