# Minimize Navigation Bar while scrolling tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to implement the same behavior/functionality that instagram uses when scrolling through a tableview the navigation bar minimizes. I've researched this and utilized the solution found here:

[Imitate iOS 7 Facebook hide/show expanding/contracting Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar)

This solution is really useful but I'm running into a problem. I'm using a section header in section 0 of my tableView. When I scroll up, the navigation bar hides, but the tableView does not adjust its size for the navigation bar changes. This leaves a gap when the navigation bar collapses which looks like this:

[image: Before scroll up]

[image: After scroll up]

I've found other various articles online saying that this problem has to do with the contentInset of the tableView but I could not find more details on this. If anyone has any advice on how to fix this problem that would be awesome.

Comment: Did you try updating the frame of the `tableView` in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods?

Answer (score 1):

I think here's what you want, or you can put the to the header or row at index 0 of the tableView if it's a custom navigation bar, you can just hide the header row at index 0.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= distance)
     {
         //scrollup

         [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated:YES];
     }
     else if(scrollView.contentOffset.y >= distance)
     {
        //scrolldown
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar setItems:nil];
            [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use yourTable/scrollToRowAtIndexPath. 
When go to indexPath difference first row -> hide navigation 
When go to first row -> show navigation

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` and table's delegate can also act as a scroll view's delegate. So you can use all methods from `UIScrollViewDelegate` for your table (implementing them in table's delegate), e.g.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use UINavigationController 's new property: `hidesBarsOnSwipe`?