# How to hide the navigation bar and toolbar as scroll down? Swift (like myBridge app)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I want to hide a toolbar and nav bar as I scroll down a page. And return it as I scroll up. How is this possible?

How would I go about detecting the drag? Do I use pan gesture or is this down with the scrollview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imitate iOS 7 Facebook hide/show expanding/contracting Navigation Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar). Please scroll through the answers. There are Swift answers in there.

Answer (score 104):

Try this simple approach: Tested in `Swift 3`

```
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    if(velocity.y>0) {
        //Code will work without the animation block.I am using animation block incase if you want to set any delay to it.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { 
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true) 
            self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
            print("Hide")
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { 
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
            self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
            print("Unhide")
        }, completion: nil)    
      }
   }
```

**Output:** `Updated`

[image]

**Note:** If you passing any data from this VC to another VC that embedded with `navigationController`.You may need to `unhide` the `NavigationBar`.

Comment: Hi, this worked to hide it and unhide it, But how did you do to have the yellow part below the status bar?

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios normally when you hide navigationBar.statusbar background goes transparent.I settled viewController background colour to yellow and tableview contentInset top padding to statusBar frame height(20px down).

Comment: @Joe Worked perfectly for me ! I shortened it to `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(velocity.y > 0, animated: true)` as I had only nav bars to take care of !

Comment: Good solution, however if you have long list and put finger to stop scroll navbar appears.
A put "if else" clause where velocity.y < 0 - covers this case. 
Also I can't find how to fix a bug when tapping statusBar and scrollToTop activated - scrollViewWillEndDragging doesn't detect it.

Comment: This works for me if I completely remove self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true): in case I don't, when I go back from the detail view to the master, my layout gets completely messed up for unknown reasons

Comment: @3000 May help. Read again the bottom *Note* in my answer.

Comment: @Joe: I did it in the viewWillAppear of the master VC but it didn't work. Maybe I should try on the back button tap. Another thing I must say: in my project, I did not want to hide the toolbar but the code doesn't hide it, for some unknown reason  :-)

Comment: @Joe: the toolbar thing didn' work because I had a tabBar, not a toolbar (in fact, if I reference the tab bar it works)   :-)

Comment: @3000 Toolbar is a subclass if tabBarController. Check the documentation. The code you looking for is something similar to “self.tabBarController?.setTabbarHidden(true, animated=true)”.

Comment: @Joe: in fact, I tried it before posting (setTabbarHidden doesn't exist, there's a boolean value isHidden you can use)  :-)

Comment: @Joe It will not work in the case when you take `UINavigationBar` in class

Answer (score 28):

Easily to do this:

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Comment: Using only this approach the navigation bar disappears forever

Comment: @Kappe Make sure that the top constraint of your scroll view or table view is the Superview and not the Safe Area or Top Layout Guide. That should fix it.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion the proper way to handle navigation bar in Tableview as follows. This would applicable if we have section header in Tableview.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y < 0 {
      navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

   } else {
      navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can try `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true` in viewDidAppear also you can use hide on swipe.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everyone, the way I went with was using AMScrollingController.

https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar

It's updated for Swift 3

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5 Xcode 10.3

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
  }
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is very good option for that

Easily hide and show a view controller's navigationBar/tabBar as a user scrolls
https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar

```
import HidingNavigationBar

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var hidingNavBarManager: HidingNavigationBarManager?
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        hidingNavBarManager = HidingNavigationBarManager(viewController: self, scrollView: tableView)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        hidingNavBarManager?.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        hidingNavBarManager?.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        hidingNavBarManager?.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    //// TableView datasoure and delegate

    func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
        hidingNavBarManager?.shouldScrollToTop()

        return true
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift UI

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    // other customizations
    navigationBar.tintColor = .white
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in my scrollview, as I was using components other than `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, not sure if it works for you, but it's working perfectly for me:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let totalTop = (UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height ?? 0) + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0)
    let shouldHideNavBar = scrollView.contentOffset.y > -(totalTop - 20) // 20 is an arbitrary number I added to compensate for some of scrolling
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(shouldHideNavBar, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use these lines of code :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *)scroll {
    // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
    CGFloat currentOffset = scroll.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat maximumOffset = scroll.contentSize.height - scroll.frame.size.height;

    // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.0) {
        self.navigationController?.hidden = YES;
    }
    else{
        self.navigationController?.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C. Please post answers in the appropriate language.

Comment: please use scrollViewWillEndDragging delegate method