# Swift - Navigation Bar won't hide on scroll

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

I am posting this after following this thread:

[How to hide the navigation bar and toolbar as scroll down? Swift (like myBridge app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667985/how-to-hide-the-navigation-bar-and-toolbar-as-scroll-down-swift-like-mybridge)

I have the following Nav bar:

[image]

And I want it to disappear when I scroll down in the `UICollectionView` and appear when I scroll up.

I have added the code from the posted thread above:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    if(velocity.y>0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { 
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true) 
            self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
            print("Hide")
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { 
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
            self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
            print("Unhide")
        }, completion: nil)    
      }
   }
```

But when I scroll down it won't disappear (Neither will the `TabBar`).

Can someone point me to what I might be doing wrong? Does it have anything to do with the fact I am scrolling the `UICollectionView` and perhaps not the `View`?

Comment: Try adding `layoutIfNeeded()` in the animation block before your print statements.

Comment: Value of type 'ProductsCollectionViewController' has no member 'layoutIfNeeded'

Comment: You need to apply it to root view of ViewController... `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: Added, it doesn't work..

Comment: Okay, then the problem is that your method `scrollViewWillEndDragging` is not being invoked. You need to make your `ViewController` a UIScrollView delegate.