# How to show an image behind a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift

Any ideas how to show an image behind a navigation bar and also show the "full" navigation bar on scrolling down?

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40670196/8918347

Comment: @artemchen Do u need the NavigationBar Hide/Show or Do u want the Function of NavigationBar in the Image ?

Comment: `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the navigation bar and toolbar as scroll down? Swift (like myBridge app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667985/how-to-hide-the-navigation-bar-and-toolbar-as-scroll-down-swift-like-mybridge)

Answer (score 1):

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Simply you can do like this. I hope It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your Reference Image can be achieved by using the below code.
Here 180 is the header size of the `TableView`.With This condition `scrollOffset > 180` you can change the `UIColor` of the `NavigationBar` elements.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
         self.navigationView.alpha = scrollOffset > 180 ? 1 : 0
    }

}
```

In your Header of the `TableView`, you should assign the Desired Image as `HeaderView`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can add image in the title view of the navigation item in viewDidLoad() of the view controller**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let image = UIImage(named: "YOURIMAGE")
    navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
}
```

**And here is an example how you can do it with CGRect.**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 38, height: 38))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "YOURIMAGE")
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```