# User interaction disabled until the navigation bar animation gets completed in iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a tableView, if the user scrolls it up, I hide the navigation bar and show back if scrolls down. It is working perfectly fine on iOS 12 but in iOS 13 user interaction gets disabled until the navigation bar animation gets completed. Here is the code to show/hide navigation bar:

```
[controller.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

So, basically user interaction is disabled for `UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration` constant time.

Show/hide handling is done on `scrollViewWillEndDragging` delegate method.

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667985/how-to-hide-the-navigation-bar-and-toolbar-as-scroll-down-swift-like-mybridge

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik hide/show is working fine, issue is that "In iOS 13 user interaction gets disabled until the navigation bar animation gets completed"