# How to hide the navigation bar as scroll down, when constraints are programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, programmatically-created, programmatic-config

I'm doing all my UI programatically, to avoid a massive view controller I have a class of type UIView where I'm declaring all my UI elements.

I'm declaring my scrollView like this:

```
class RegisterUIView: UIView {

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scroll: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
        scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scroll
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(scrollView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor)
        ])      
   }
}
```

After the declaration. I create an instance of RegisterUIView in my ViewController.
And in the `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` I used the variable `hidesBarsOnSwipe`, to hide the navigation bar.
When I scroll down the bar hides, but when I scroll up the bar is not unhiding.

I read in other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667985/how-to-hide-the-navigation-bar-and-toolbar-as-scroll-down-swift-like-mybridge/40670196) that I need to set the top constraint to the superview.
How can is set the constraints to the superview?, when I try to set it the app crashes, and is obviously because there is no superview.

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

    private let registerView: RegisterUIView = {
        let view: RegisterUIView = RegisterUIView(frame: .zero)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupLayout()  
    }

    func setupLayout() {
        view.addSubview(registerView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            registerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            registerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            registerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            registerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the scroll view to the subview before adding constraints. Your app crashes because you're adding constraints to an object, not in the subview.

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

add that line of code to the top of your `setupLayout()` function before your start adding constraints.