# Implementing Navigation-bar and an Extension view attached to the bottom of nav-bar

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3, uinavigationbar

What's the right way to implement a hides-on-scroll navigation bar along with an extension view attached to the navigation bar's bottom. And on scroll the navigation bar gets hidden and the extension view sticks to the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TLYShyNavBar](https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar) library to implement this feature if you want extension view to stick to status bar. If you just want navigationBar to hide along with extension then use hidesBarsOnSwipe property

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar?noredirect=1&lq=1) to read more about this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @suhit, I'm currently using TLYShyNavBar in my project. But I wanted to know if there are any other ways and also the right way of implementing it.

Comment: You can use custom collection view  to implement this feature if you have collection view, table view headers also works. You can use headers or reusable view instead of extension view to get this functionality of you don't want to use third party library.